# Generate big zip file in asp net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, zip, out-of-memory

I'm building a MVC controller action which build a zip file containing two files :

- Some metadata serialized from the database.
- A related content file actually store in an azure storage blob

So far, my controller works fine until a certain file size. Then when the content from azure gets too big I have an out of memory exception certainely related to the fact that i'm writing stuff in the server's memory which is not infinite.

So now I'm wondering which approach should I take ? Write stuff in a temp path on the server or are there other options ?

Here's my controller aciton for the reference :

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Download(Guid? id)
    {

        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var cIApplication = await _context.CIApplications
            .AsNoTracking()
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
        if (cIApplication == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        //Serialize metadata : this will always be small
        byte[] metaData = BinSerializer.SerializeToByteArrayAsync<CIApplication>(cIApplication);

        //GetFile from Azure blob : This can reach several GB
        //StorageManagement is an helper class to manipulate Azure storage objects
        StorageManagement storage = new StorageManagement();
        byte[] content = await storage.GetBlobToStream("application", $"{cIApplication.ID}.zip");

        //Zip It and send it
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var archive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
            {
                var zipArchiveEntry = archive.CreateEntry($"{cIApplication.ID}.bin", CompressionLevel.Fastest);
                using (var zipStream = zipArchiveEntry.Open()) zipStream.Write(metaData, 0, metaData.Length);

                zipArchiveEntry = archive.CreateEntry($"{cIApplication.ID}.zip", CompressionLevel.Fastest);
                using (var zipStream = zipArchiveEntry.Open()) zipStream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
            }
            return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/zip", $"{cIApplication.Publisher} {cIApplication.Name} {cIApplication.Version}.zip");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Typically, yes, you'd spool to the file system, to keep memory utilization minimal. However, I believe that creating a zip out of this is going to cause you issues regardless, since it will have to loaded into memory anyways for that. You'll likely have to just vertically scale your RAM on the server to compensate. You may also consider breaking this out into a background process that can run on a different server with less apps vying for RAM. Then, you can even set up a queue so you don't have to deal with multiple zipping operations at once.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Azure, but your problem is typical. You should download `content` in chunks and ZIP it in chunks. Google shows me some results in minutes for `azure blob stream chunk download` and `c# zip chunk`.